# How to import all global function with one line of code in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to import all of these global function with ONE line of code?

```
package utils.relocator
{

    public function getCenterX(displayObject:DisplayObject):Number
    {
        return displayObject.x + displayObject.width / 2;
    }

    public function getCenterY(displayObject:DisplayObject):Number
    {
        return displayObject.y + displayObject.height / 2;
    }

    public function setCenterX(displayObject:DisplayObject, newCenterX:Number):void {
        displayObject.x = newCenterX - displayObject.width / 2;
    }

    public function setCenterY(displayObject:DisplayObject, newCenterY:Number):void {
        displayObject.y = newCenterY - displayObject.height / 2;
    }

}
```

I don't want to import like this:

```
    import utils.relocator.getCenterX;
    import utils.relocator.getCenterY;
    import utils.relocator.setCenterX;
    import utils.relocator.setCenterY;
```

I've tried:

```
    import utils.*;
```

or

```
    import utils.relocator.*;
```

but it seems like it only works for class not global function. And I get errors like this: `Error: Call to a possibly undefined method setCenterX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about package-level functions, like for example [`flash.utils`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html) package or the [`as3-utils`](https://github.com/as3/as3-utils) project, ...

And to get your package-level function working you should put it into an `.as` file which has the name of your function and should be in the same path as your package.

So for your question, you should create 4 `.as` files ( one for every function ) like, for example, for your `getCenterX` function :

**File path :**

```
utils/relocator/getCenterX.as
```

**File content :**

```
package utils.relocator
{   
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public function getCenterX(displayObject:DisplayObject):Number
    {   
        return displayObject.x + displayObject.width / 2;
    }
}
```

And then you will just import it :

[image]

And then to use it ( use <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> / <kbd>**Command**</kbd> (Mac) + <kbd>**Space**</kbd> to show the completion popup menu ) :

[image]

And finally you will get something like this :

```
import utils.relocator.*;

// mc is a MovieClip (100x100) in the stage at (100, 100)
trace(getCenterX(mc));  // gives : 150
```

For more information about package-level functions, take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/packages.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader) and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9e.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: I tried to import those methods one by one like the way I said don't want to. My IDE (FlashDevelop) recognized them but when compiling I still got errors like: `Call to a possibly undefined method setCenterX`

Comment: @DleanJeans Try to verify if you have put the `setCenterX.as` in the right path : `utils/relocator` ...